# Passing metadata when slicing subclass of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a class which inherits from pandas.DataFrame. In this class metadata is added (not to columns, but to the class instance):

```
class MeasurementPoint(pandas.DataFrame):

    def __init__(self, data, metadata):
        super(MeasurementPoint, self).__init__(data)
        self.metadata = metadata

    # in order to return MeasurementPoint instead of DataFrame, define _constructor
    def _constructor(self):
        return MeasurementPoint
```

If I slice the class, I get a TypeError since `__init__` is missing the required argument `metadata`. 
I've tried to modify `_constructor` to pass the `metadata`, but without succes.
I've also tried to add the `metadata` to the class as an additional property (`_metadata' = ['metadata']`) as described here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html, but to no avail.

How can I get the class MeasurementPoint to retain the metadata when it's being sliced?

Comment: As the pandas' **internals** documentation suggests, take a closer look at the geopandas package [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L51) which should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether it's considered good form to answer your own questions, but the following seems to work:

```
class MeasurementPoint(pandas.DataFrame):

    _metadata = ['metadata']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        metadata = kwargs.pop('metadata', {})
        super(MeasurementPoint, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.metadata = metadata

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MeasurementPoint
```